# ExpandableListView, как сделать дерево (MultiExpandableListView)?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Здравствуйте подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на главную часть списка он опускался в низ и там были подпункты которые также можно было открыть то есть визуально это выглядело примерно так:

►1 Главное название (уровень 1)

► 1.1 подпункт (уровень 2)

1.1.1 подпункт (уровень 3)

1.1.2 подпункт (уровень 3)

1.1.3 подпункт (уровень 3)

► 1.2 подпункт (уровень 2)

1.2.1 подпункт (уровень 3)

1.2.2 подпункт (уровень 3)

1.2.3 подпункт (уровень 3)

► 1.1 подпункт (уровень 2)

1.3.1 подпункт (уровень 3)

1.3.2 подпункт (уровень 3)

1.3.3 подпункт (уровень 3)

►2 Главное название (уровень 1)

►2.1 подпункт (уровень 2)

2.1.1 подпункт (уровень 3)

2.1.2 подпункт (уровень 3)

2.1.3 подпункт (уровень 3)

► 2.2 подпункт (уровень 2)

2.2.1 подпункт (уровень 3)

2.2.2 подпункт (уровень 3)

2.2.3 подпункт (уровень 3)

►2.1 подпункт (уровень 2)

2.3.1 подпункт (уровень 3)

2.3.2 подпункт (уровень 3)

2.3.3 подпункт (уровень 3)

►3 Главное название (уровень 1)

И так далее …

*Вот что я смог сделать*

**XML файл**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/I_1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.eftguide.R;

public class ItemsActivity extends Activity {

    ItemsAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_items_1);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.I_1);

        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ItemsAdapter (this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            //���������� ������� �� ������� ����:
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " �������",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " �������",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        //Добавляем данные о пунктах списка:
        listDataHeader.add("Barter items");
        listDataHeader.add("Gear");
        listDataHeader.add("Weapon parts & mods");
        listDataHeader.add("Weapons");
        listDataHeader.add("Ammo");
        listDataHeader.add("Provisions");
        listDataHeader.add("Medical treatment");
        listDataHeader.add("Keys");
        listDataHeader.add("Info items");
        listDataHeader.add("Special equipment");
        listDataHeader.add("Maps");
        listDataHeader.add("Money");

        //Добавляем данные о подпунктах:
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.1");
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.2");
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.3");
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.4");
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.5");
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.6");
        top250.add("Подпункт 1.7");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("Подпункт 2.1");
        nowShowing.add("Подпункт 2.2");
        nowShowing.add("Подпункт 2.3");
        nowShowing.add("Подпункт 2.4");
        nowShowing.add("Подпункт 2.5");
        nowShowing.add("Подпункт 2.6");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("Подпункт 3.1");
        comingSoon.add("Подпункт 3.2");
        comingSoon.add("Подпункт 3.3");
        comingSoon.add("Подпункт 3.4");
        comingSoon.add("Подпункт 3.5");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.eftguide.R;


public class ItemsAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    //Названия заголовков
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    //Данные для элементов подпунктов:
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items_3, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.I_3);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items_2, null);
        }

        TextView I_2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.I_2);
        I_2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        I_2.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: То что получилось]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) к примеру есть библиотека с нужным вам компонентом. Получается вот как:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По интеграции все тоже просто:

1. Добавляем зависимость в градл:

   ```
   implementation 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
   ```
2. Дальше добавляем ваше дерево:

   ```
   TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
   TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("MyParentNode");
   TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("ChildNode0");
   TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("ChildNode1");
   parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
   root.addChild(parent);
   ```
3. Дальше добавляем все дерево в layout:

   ```
   AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
   containerView.addView(tView.getView());
   ```
4. Добавляем класс-адаптер для поддержки:

   ```
   public class MyHolder extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<IconTreeItem> {
   ...
   @Override
   public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, IconTreeItem value) {
       final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_node, null, false);
       TextView tvValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.node_value);
       tvValue.setText(value.text);

       return view;
   }
   ...
   public static class IconTreeItem {
       public int icon;
       public String text;
   }
   ```

   }
5. Подключаем адаптер:

   ```
    IconTreeItem nodeItem = new IconTreeItem();
    TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(mContext));
   ```
6. Обрабатываем клики:

   ```
    TreeNode.setClickListener(TreeNodeClickListener listener);
    AndroidTreeView.setDefaultViewHolder
    AndroidTreeView.setDefaultNodeClickListener
   ```

Вроде как-то так.

Comment: А что именно отвечает за добавление 2-го уровня то есть : (1 уровень) (2 уровень) (2 уровень) какая часть кода? и где она находится ? в адаптере, активити или где ?